# Can't run NMAKE in the command prompt after upgrade to Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, command-prompt

I have some power shell scripts file it uses both MSBUILD.exe and NMAKE, I invoke it by command prompt not developer command prompt of VS 2017, but it is not recognized after executed VsMSBuildCmd.bat file.

But it works fine on the Visual Studio 2015.

Besides, it is working through developer command prompt of VS 2017.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can't run NMAKE in the command prompt after upgrade to Visual Studio 2017

I got the same result "*'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command*" after executed the `VsMSBuildCmd.bat` file from VS2017 installation directory: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Tools`:

[image]

After test, I found the solution for this issue, after executed the `VsMSBuildCmd.bat`, still need to executed the `vcvars.bat`. The path of `vcvars.bat` is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd\ext
```

In this case, NMAKE command would be recognized in command prompt:

[image]

Comment: I don't find vcvars.bat in that specified location.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like the new location for *Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt* is here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools\LaunchDevCmd.bat
```

Comment: What does that have to do with nmake?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't see vcvars , you should install msvc component.

[image]